# Сериализация и дамп стека lua для лога из С++

Tags: c++, lua

Имеется некий большой скрипт написанный на луа.
В этот скрипт идет очень много разных данных.
Для работы хотел-бы делать дамп стека, сериализовать его и потом на его основе делать отладку.
Вопрос следующий, возможно ли задампить весь скрипт с учетом метатаблиц и прочего?

Comment: Дамп стека?  Тот который генерится `debug.traceback` и `luaL_traceback` ?

Comment: В API есть функция создания стека, а именно luaL_newstate. Вот её и надо мне дампить

Comment: какого ещё стека???  это функция создания виртуальной машины Lua.  пустой машины.  то есть, дампить там пока нечего )))